# Instead of iteration method, can we solve this matrix computation?

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices, complex-numbers

I have a simple problem with matrix compuation.
Matices what I have are $A_f$ matrix with $(M \times N)$, $B_f$ matrix(or vector) with $(N \times 1)$.
I just want to calculate $|A_fB_f|^2$ for $F$ iteration.
In other words, It can be explained as computer code that I would like to use $F$ times for loop.

If we calculate accumulation between $A_f$ and $B_f$, it is easy to be switched just by concatenating as

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & \cdots A_F \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} B_1 \\
B_2\\
\vdots\\
B_F\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, if we try to calculate absolute square of complex matrices $A_f$ and $B_f$, it becomes bothersome problem.
If we try to calculate this matrix computation without for loop iteration procedure, we need to do not concatenate but extend them into huge matrix for $A$ as below:

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & O & O & \cdots & O\\ O & A_2 & O & \cdots & O \\  O & O & O & \cdots & A_F \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} B_1 \\
B_2\\
\vdots\\
B_F\end{bmatrix}.$$

Because elements of $A_f$ and $B_f$ are all complex value, there is no meaning of accumulating.
 This matrix increases with square of $F$.
In this case left matrix has $((M \times F) \times (N \times F))$ element with too much zero elements.
 Above matrix computation has too much inefficient calculation because of plenty of zero elements.
 
Is there no other way for resolving this matrix computation?

Any comment, I really appreciate you!
Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,
Albert